# DOMXpath Query Extracting Information

Tags: php, html, xpath

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($htmlcode);
$xpath = new DOMXpath($doc);
$elements = $xpath->query("//*[@id='detail']/div[1]/h3/text()");

return var_dump($elements);
```

How do i actually retrieve the xpath correctly? it's returning

```
object(DOMNodeList)#4 (1) {
  ["length"]=>
  int(1)
}
```

When i do a var_dump($doc); It contains the html as ["textContent"]=> string(22304)

I copied the xpath using google chrome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It isn't possible to introspect a `DOMNodeList` using `var_dump()` as you might expect. You'll have to access the list item `0` and it's node value:

```
$elements = $xpath->query("//*[@id='detail']/div[1]/h3/text()");
if($elements->length === 1) {
    echo $elements->item(0)->nodeValue;
} else {
   ...
}
```

Comment: Hi @hel2mgl. Thank you I will read up more on NodeList. my site uses charset="gbk" how do i main the characters , any idea? I realized the text are not Chinese anymore.

Comment: I would suggest using `utf8` as the charset

Comment: Am i right to say that i have to convert the gbk characters to utf-8 for it to display properly? Not sure if the characters will still stay